# How to use Bend Modifier to create perfect polygons, (pentagon, hexagron, septagon, etc...)?

Tags: transforms

I watched a youtube tutorial way back that did this using a circle as a reference onto a plank, and depending on the number of loop cuts, you could create a perfect polygon easily and if the two ends didn't line up there was a modifier checkbox that would automatically join the two ends together.
I found that I didn't like the placing of a circle and simply specifying the number of segments.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That'll be the Screw modifier, operating on a single vertex mesh at (radius) away from its object origin?

[image]